# What is the best way to add logging for creation of a Django Model instance?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Suppose I have the models defined in my Django models.py file as shown below.

I would like to add some generic code such that every time any instances of modelA or modelB are created, a log message is recorded that looks like this: "created an instance of modelA: Field1 = A1, Field2 = A2" -- without any other side effects.

How can I do it?

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class modelA(models.Model):
    field1 = models.TextField(default="A1")
    field2 = models.TextField(default="A2")
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Field1 = %s, Field2 = %s" % (self.field1, self.field2)

class modelB(models.Model):
    field1 = models.TextField(default="B1")
    field2 = models.TextField(default="B2")
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Field1 = %s, Field2 = %s" % (self.field1, self.field2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


@receiver(post_save)
def log_creation(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created and isinstance(instance, (ModelA, ModelB)):
        logger.info("created an instance of %s : %s", sender.__name__, instance)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!
@bruno-desthuilliers, can I create a similar callback for deletion of these models?

Comment: You can see all the available signals in the docs -https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/

Comment: Depending on your requirements you may also find it easier to use a preexisting Django model auditing app -https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/model-audit/

Answer (score 1):

You could override the save method, and add a call to logger

or setup a [signal receiver](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/) and add your logger there.

If you think you might eventually extend this logging to more models it might be easier to add the functionality as a signal receiver and subscribe to the relevant models `post_save` signal